# setting UIViewControllers as properties within other UIViewController

Tags: ios

Till now, I've been using controller or controllers like UITabbarController, or UINavigation controller to manage the UiviewController hierarchy. however, in the current project, i've been presented with a situation where my friends are recommending that I do away with controller of controllers and instead instantiate sub-UIViewControllers within the RootViewController and keep them as attributes. My question is whether this is a good practice MVC wise and memory management wise? (this is for iOS 5.0 with ARC)

The project requires a screen to have a header, main content area, and footer. the header and footer present dynamic content, but are the same for all screens but in the main content area, different screens can be presented either transitioning in from the right (like navigation controller would do it) or would appear modally.

I've tried to stick to MVC with one ViewController managing one view hierarchy... the above seems to go against it, but it seems to help in the situation.. so is this the right way to go or am I missing some other more optimal way?? Pls help

Thanks for your help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Why even have to have references to the view controllers themselves if you can just keep a reference to the view they manage?  Sure it breaks MVC, but I love being able to divide reusable interface classes and then simply add their view's as subviews.  It works, so long as you are smart about the whole thing.  Is there anything specific about this pattern you'd like help with?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this blog..Hope it helps you,
http://borkwarellc.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/qff-kitchen-mvc-part-1/